# Installing PostGIS gives error: could not find libpq?

Tags: postgis, installation, linux

After giving the command `./configure`, it is showing that:

> pQserverversion in -lpq not found. configure: error: could not find libpq.

What does it mean?

I am installing PostGIS 1.5 using Red hat Linux (32 bit) version 5.3. PostgreSQL version 8.3.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? What are you trying to do? What data do you have? etc

Comment: ... and why the ancient PostgreSQL, RHEL and PostGIS? You shouldn't be doing anything new at all on a system that old, it should be in maintenance mode while you work on an upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Craig. Your redhat version is very old. Any way, the problem is that you need the package libpq-dev installed.

```
yum install libpq-dev
```